# Solving kinematic ODEs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matlab, eulers-method, discrete-time

I am making a particle filter implementation using the kinematic equations as my state transition function, that is to say:
$$
\dot{p} = v\\
\dot{v} = a
$$
where $a$ is assumed to be given. My first attempt was using the backward Euler method:
$$
p_{k+1} = p_k + T_s v_k\\
v_{k+1} = v_k + T_s a_k
$$
for $T_s = 0.01$ and $|a| \leq 0.5$. The velocity plot is more or less perfect, but there is substantial error between actual position, found by MATLABs cumtrapz, and the Euler method derived position.
[image]
Plot was created roughly by

```
p = zeros(N,1);
v = zeros(N,1);
for i=2:N
  p(k) = p(k-1) + Ts*v(k-1);
  v(k) = v(k-1) + Ts*a(k-1);
end
```

Decreasing the sampling time has virtually 0 impact.

I have read online about Euler method being a first order discretization method so I figure it has something to do with that given that this is a second order set of ODEs?

I figure I should look into higher order solvers, [e.g.](https://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/Differential_Equations_Notes/node5.html), as an alternative. Given this is a particle filter implementation the solution method needs to be quite computationally cheap.

Is my understanding of the problem completely incorrect? Also is using ERK a viable solution? Or is the problem here somewhere else.

Note: plots made using MATLAB

Comment: Assuming p and v depend on time, you can integrate the second equation straight away to obtain v=at+$c_1$ and then substituting into the first we have ˙=at+$c_1$ which means that $p$=$at^2/2$+$c_1t$+$c_2$,  which are the equations of motion.

Comment: I mean yeah but that doesn't really address the inaccuracies with the discretization methods. That formulation should be equivalent with the system of 2 equations form shown above. The $\dot{p} = v$ and $\dot{v} = a$

Comment: Plot the equations of the graphs?

Comment: I added an edit with rough pseudo code on how the plot data was made. I think that was what you were asking for?